# Which library is used to access the Gmail emails using J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, google-talk

i want to develop gtalk application for the mobile

please tell me the name of library that is used to access the gmail account thr J2ME

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Question title says you want to access gmail emails , but in the description it says to develop gtalk application .

If you are looking for gtalk client development  check out the following resources

Why you need to develop gtalk client for Mobiles , There is already a Plenty of gtalk   . To learn you can try with Open Source Application to get started .

[MGtalk](http://mgtalk.sourceforge.net/) :  Google Talk for mobile  project .Jabber client for j2me midp 2.0 platform, supports some Google Talk server features. May run on any j2me midp 2.0 mobile phone or communicator.

[GTMobile](http://code.google.com/p/gtmobile/) is a client of Google Talk that run on java phones. It requires CLDC 1.1 and MIDP 2.0 support.

Both uses [JabberService](http://jabber.com)

**EDIT**  If you are looking for gmail in Mobile these API will come Handy for you

- [Mail4me](http://mail4me.objectweb.org/)  : is a lightweight implementation of the popular SMTP, POP3 and IMAP protocols - including MIME support - allowing wireless J2ME/MIDP devices to access the e-mail service at any time, and from any place

  [API](http://mail4me.objectweb.org/software/documentation/api/index.html) docs for Mail4me
- [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/index.html) can also be used for developing .
- [mMail](http://www.mmail.pl/en/index.html) midlet is a useful email client for mobile Java (J2ME) devices supporting GPRS data transfer. It is able to send and receive simple plain-text email messages.

  Hope this Helps !

Answer (score 0):

JavaMail can not be using on the J2me Platform

Comment: Check the below link some of the Mobile agents listed in Sun Java Mail Third party list http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html